# Transfering random index of array to another array JAVA

Tags: java

How do I transfer the index of a number I received randomly in an array to another array? I'm trying to make an application of some kind of Question&Answer thing and when I call a random question I want to call that answer too. But I don't know how to do it. How can I transfer the index that I called randomly question's to the answer's array?

```java
package javaapplication18;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication18 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Oyun başlıyor");
        
        String[] kelimeler = new String[] {"bilgisayar","fare","buzdolabi","kitap","otomobil"};
        
        String rastgeleKelime = kelimeler[(int) (Math.random() * kelimeler.length)];
        
        System.out.println("Sorulan kelime "+ rastgeleKelime.length()+" harfli.");
        
        char[] harfler = new char[rastgeleKelime.length()];
        
        for(int i = 0; i<harfler.length; i++){
            harfler[i] = '.';
        }
        
        int haklar = 3;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(haklar > 0){
            System.out.print("Kalan hak: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < haklar; i++){
                System.out.print("X");
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Tahmin: ");
            
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            char harf = input.charAt(0);
            
            boolean tahmin = false;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < rastgeleKelime.length(); i++){
                char l = rastgeleKelime.charAt(i);
                
                if(l == harf){
                    harfler[i] = l;
                    tahmin = true;
                }
            }
            
            if(!tahmin){
                haklar = haklar-1;   
            }
            
            boolean oyunsonu = true;
            
            System.out.print("Kelime: ");
            
            for(int i = 0; i < harfler.length; i++){
                if(harfler[i] == '.'){
                    oyunsonu = false;
                }
                
                System.out.print(harfler[i]);
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            
            if(oyunsonu){
                System.out.println("Tebrikler. Kazandınız!");
                break;
            }
            
            if(haklar == 0){
                System.out.println("Kaybettiniz! Kelime: "+ rastgeleKelime);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Oyun bitti");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you model the question and answer to form a class on its own? You would be able to store and retrieve the questions and answers easily. Additionally, since your code is written in Turkish it is kind of hard to follow along. Consider writing it in English if possible.

Comment: I will try that in classes, thank you. And I'm new here so I apologize for my inexperience here, I will try to write it in English next time.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] the question now for others who find this post

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "transfer", but given two arrays of the same type and size, you simply would do `b[i] = a[i]`. Or you can create a class that holds both answers and questions, then create a list of those rather than two separate arrays

Comment: I was trying to do call random question from an array and I want to call that question's answer too but they are in different arrays so how do I call the random question's answer? @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. I created rnd object from using Random library. And then I assigned rnd to an "a" object and then I called this object in my Array so it worked. Thank you for your supports.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Oyun başlıyor");
    
    String[] cümleler = new String[] {"Elephant", "Deer", "Fish", "Crocodile", "Cat"};
    
    String[] kelimeler = new String[] {"bilgisayar","fare","buzdolabi","kitap","otomobil"};
    
    Random random =new Random();
    int a=random.nextInt(5);
    
    String rastgeleKelime = kelimeler[a];
    String rastgeleCümle = cümleler[a];
    
    System.out.println(rastgeleCümle);
    
    System.out.println("Sorulan kelime "+ rastgeleKelime.length()+" harfli.");
    
    char[] harfler = new char[rastgeleKelime.length()];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<harfler.length; i++){
        harfler[i] = '.';
    }
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to look at the `Arrays.fill` method

Comment: Strong suggestion: I'd consider substituting a Java  [List<String>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for a String[] array.  I would also, per  
João Dias's suggestion above, consider encapsulating all of your "Q&A" functionality (including your List<String> as a "private" member) in a Java class

Comment: Thank you for your supports. I will pay attention to your recommendations